# Removing "child said into stdout/stderr" prefix from logs in GAE php74 standard environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud, fpm

I'm running a php74 standard environment in Google App Engine and outputting logs to `php://stdout`. Unfortunately, all the logs are prefixed with `child X said into stdout` and all the PHP errors are prefixed with `child X said into stderr`. Outside of GAE, I've addressed this by modifying the php-fpm runtime config to set `catch_workers_output = yes` but on the **standard** environment, you can't change the runtime config, you can only set `php.ini` changes.

Is there a way to remove this prefix on the standard environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the App Engine's Standard [configuration reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref) where all elements are listed, there is no option to remove the log prefix.
Since it's a full list of options, such a feature would be mentioned there if it was supported.

In this case, you may want to create a new [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0) for GCP to consider it.

Comment: Gotcha. Was hoping this wouldn't be the case, but looks like it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option to remove the decoration:

```
 decorate_workers_output bool
```

> Enable the output decoration for the worker's output when catch_workers_output is enabled. Default value: yes. Available as of PHP 7.3.0.

See more in the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#decorate-workers-output